# British occupations in Europe during the Napoleonic wars

Tags: napoleonic-wars

It's hard to find information about the British occupations in Europe during the Napoleonic Wars, specially after 1812.

Were Belgium, Mallorca, Sicily and/or Sardinia occupied by the British?

I know that the British attempted to invade Corsica but failed.

Comment: What's your definition of "occupation" in this context? With the exception of a few islands, the British army was tied up in the Spanish peninsular (and North America) for the period of interest. Their actions in Sicily and southern Italy were as a allied force (with the Neapolitan Monarchy).

Comment: Where they had control. Likewise the British and Americans had control over large parts of Western Europe after D-day in 1944-45. I simply want to know where the British had control during the Napoleonic Wars from 1813 to 1815.